# Require password to access sites not on whitelist

Tags: gateway, whitelist

I have a situation where I need to set up a domain whitelist and block access to all other sites. The trick now is that the network owner needs to bypass the whitelist on occasion.

Is there a way to to this with ClearOS? If not ClearOS how about another gateways server?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/162824/require-password-to-access-sites-not-on-whitelist

Comment: @warren - That is odd.

Comment: I figured it was probably a goof - just wanted to make you aware of it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClearOS is simply a preconfugred Linux distribution - which comes with a web proxy. There's very little information on the site about what the web proxy is and how the system is configured but the following may apply....

If I were starting from scratch then:

1) block all access to the outside world except for the gateway machine, SMTP server and any machinse which have incoming connections from the internet (and disable routing on the these boxes)

2) Install 'squid' on the gateway machine (see [this article](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/3871) for an example of a simple authenticated web access setup)

3) configure the browsers to use the squid server as a proxy (or set up a automatic proxy config file)

There's more information about [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) here.

C.

Comment: Squid will definitely suffice for this. I have used it for years for web-filtering with blacklists and whitelists, although not exactly like this.  Its simple and reliable.

Comment: I'm going to give this a go. If it works I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

ClearOS will allow you to configure multiple policies based on various factors such as user authentication, IP address, and other client factors. You can create a default policy for the company and then use the Dynamic DHCP allocation to place the business owner into a more open zone then all the other users. Your policy for him will apply to his IP address and thereby

To get started with this, click on the 'Select Filter Group' in the content filter and choose, add filter group.

The documentation link on the configuration page will give you specific instruction in the documentation as well as a short tutorial video.

Comment: I think that would work if the owner had a dedicated computer. But the owner maybe using any of the three workstations. The computers only have one user account or I could use a group policy. These are all point of sale workstations.